# How does this code give the correct result using a variable that was not entered

Tags: c, recursion

```
    #include<stdio.h>
const char *author ="Alexandre Santos";

int succ(int x)
{
  return x+1;
}

int pred(int x)
{
  return x-1;
}

int is_zero(int x)
{
  return x == 0;
}

int is_pos(int x)
{
  return x >= 0;
}

int sum(int x, int y)
{
 return is_zero(y)? x: sum(succ(x),pred(y));
}

int twice(int x)
{
  return sum(succ(x), pred(x));
}

int main(void)
{
 int x;
 scanf("%d", &x);
 int z = twice(x);
 printf("%d\n", z);
 return 0;
}
```

I am in the first year of university and this is one of the exercises that a professor gave. I need to calculate the double of a number just using the given functions(succ, pred, is_zero, is_pos). I tried to do it and managed to come up with a solution but to be honest I don't understand how this is working. My main doubt is how the sum function is working since it uses the variable y and in this program this variable doesn't even exist/is not inserted in the input. Any tip?

Comment: The parameters to a function (the `int x, int y` in `#sum`, for example) are _passed in_. These variables only exist for the duration of the call to the function, and are set to the value of what the function was called with. For example, if you called `twice(y)` (with a new variable `y`), then it would be treated as `x` in the `#twice` function.

Comment: The variable `x` in `sum` is completely separate from the variable `x` in `twice` and the variable `x` in `main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you called the function `twice()` with the parameter `x`, and in the function `twice()` you called the function `sum()` with the parameters `succ(x)` and `pred(x)`, the value of `succ(x)` is assigned to `x` in `sum`, and the value of `pred(x)` is assigned to `y` in `sum`.

So for example; you passed the value `10` to `x` in the input, we will call the function `twice` with a value `10`, and `twice(10)` returns the sum of `succ(10)` and `pred(10)` which are `11` and `9`, so the values `11` and `9` are passed to the function `sum` like this: `sum(11, 9)`, so in the function `sum`, the parameter `x` gets the value `11`, and the parameter `y` gets the value `9`.